# Odoo 16 MailThread._message_auto_subscribe_notify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template'

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-16

In Odoo 16, Mail Thread notify called in a custom module.

```py
if approver.user_id:
   self._message_auto_subscribe_notify([approver.user_id.partner_id.id])
```

But throwing an error,

[image]

What will be second argument for template and example of template code?

Comment: What is your desired message for the notification? Something like "you were assgigned to foo"?

Comment: Oh and as alternative you can use `message_subscribe()` instead, where a list of partner IDs is enough. But IIRC ther won't be an automatic notification using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument should be a [notification template external ID](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py#L3126) as mentioned in the function documentation

```
def _message_auto_subscribe_notify(self, partner_ids, template):
    """ Notify new followers, using a template to render the content of the
    notification message. Notifications pushed are done using the standard
    notification mechanism in mail.thread. It is either inbox either email
    depending on the partner state: no user (email, customer), share user
    (email, customer) or classic user (notification_type)

    :param partner_ids: IDs of partner to notify;
    :param template: XML ID of template used for the notification;
    """
```

As an example, check [message_user_assigned](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/140e58c5a68db674fc1d240147e4d669b29f2cad/addons/mail/data/mail_templates_chatter.xml#L5) template

```
<!-- Discuss utility templates for notifications -->
<template id="message_user_assigned">
    <span>Dear<t t-esc="object.user_id.sudo().name"/>,
    </span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span style="margin-top: 8px;">You have been assigned to the
        <t t-esc="model_description or 'document'"/>
        <t t-esc="object.display_name"/>.
    </span>
    <br/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the existing addons `project`, it's used this way in `project.py`:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    _name = "project.project"
    _description = "Project"
    _inherit=['mail.alias.mixin','mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']

# ...
# ...
self.message_notify(
                    subject=_('You have been assigned to %s', self.display_name),
                    body=assignation_msg,
                    partner_ids=user.partner_id.ids,
                    record_name=self.display_name,
                    email_layout_xmlid='mail.mail_notification_layout',
                    model_description=self_model_description,
                    mail_auto_delete=False,
                )
```

The definition of `message_notify` can be found in addons>mail>mail_thread.py:

```py
    def message_notify(self, *,
                       partner_ids=False, parent_id=False, model=False, res_id=False,
                       author_id=None, email_from=None, body='', subject=False, **kwargs):
        """ Shortcut allowing to notify partners of messages that shouldn't be
        displayed on a document. It pushes notifications on inbox or by email depending
        on the user configuration, like other notifications. """
        if self:
            self.ensure_one()
        # split message additional values from notify additional values
        msg_kwargs = dict((key, val) for key, val in kwargs.items() if key in self.env['mail.message']._fields)
        notif_kwargs = dict((key, val) for key, val in kwargs.items() if key not in msg_kwargs)

        author_id, email_from = self._message_compute_author(author_id, email_from, raise_on_email=True)

        if not partner_ids:
            _logger.warning('Message notify called without recipient_ids, skipping')
            return self.env['mail.message']

        # allow to link a notification to a document that does not inherit from
        # MailThread by supporting model / res_id
        if not (model and res_id):  # both value should be set or none should be set (record)
            model = False
            res_id = False

        msg_values = {
            'parent_id': parent_id,
            'model': self._name if self else model,
            'res_id': self.id if self else res_id,
            'message_type': 'user_notification',
            'subject': subject,
            'body': body,
            'author_id': author_id,
            'email_from': email_from,
            'partner_ids': partner_ids,
            'is_internal': True,
            'record_name': False,
            'message_id': tools.generate_tracking_message_id('message-notify'),
        }
        msg_values.update(msg_kwargs)
        # add default-like values afterwards, to avoid useless queries
        if 'subtype_id' not in msg_values:
            msg_values['subtype_id'] = self.env['ir.model.data']._xmlid_to_res_id('mail.mt_note')
        if 'reply_to' not in msg_values:
            msg_values['reply_to'] = self._notify_get_reply_to(default=email_from)[self.id if self else False]
        if 'email_add_signature' not in msg_values:
            msg_values['email_add_signature'] = True

        new_message = self._message_create(msg_values)
        self._notify_thread(new_message, msg_values, **notif_kwargs)
        return new_message
```

Comment: He's not using `message_notify` but `_message_auto_subscribe_notify`.

Comment: You are right... i just thought that the task can be achieved this way too...